# Get user object from token string in DRF?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I have a token string from [Django REST Framework's TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

I need to get the corresponding user object. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
user = Token.objects.get(key='token string').user
```

Comment: If you're getting `AttributeError: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'objects'` then add `"rest_framework.authtoken"` in **INSTALLED_APPS** section in your settings.py file.

Source : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6250#issuecomment-591192279

Answer (score 7):

If you invoke the user object directly from the `Token` class, as presented in @aliva's solution, you will get a raw partial Django User with just the fields living in the database. If you need to get the real user object, with e.g. its computed properties, you can do this:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

user_id = Token.objects.get(key=request.auth.key).user_id
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

Comment: I get  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'

Answer (score 3):

Here is **`The default authorization token model`**:

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Token(models.Model):
    """
    The default authorization token model.
    """
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        # Work around for a bug in Django:
        # https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19422
        #
        # Also see corresponding ticket:
        # https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/705
        abstract = 'rest_framework.authtoken' not in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
        verbose_name = _("Token")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tokens")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()
        return super(Token, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_key(self):
        return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

As you can see this model has **OneOnOne relations** with the `User` model.

> So if you want to get the `User` than mapped to specific `Token`:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

try:
    Token.objects.get(key="token").user
except Token.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

**For more information see [Authentication documents](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)**

Answer (score 3):

A better method to use would be to simply call `request.user` since access to the Token means an authenticated request. DjangoRestFramework gives access to `request.auth` and `request.user` on a successful TokenAuthentication.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you wanna get userid and username when obtain auth token in Django Rest Framework

More info can get from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#by-exposing-an-api-endpoint

```
# in views.py
from rest_framework.auth.models import Token
from rest_framework.auth.views import ObtainToken
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyObtainToken(ObtainToken):
   """Return User Info along with token"""
   def post(self, request, *arg, **kwarg)
       serializer = self.serializer_class(request.data, context={'request':request})
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       user = serializer.valided_data['user']
       token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user)
       return Response(
            {
                 'token': token.key,
                 'username': user.username,
                 'userid': user.pk
            })
# in urls.py
urlpatterns += [path(r'api/obtain_auth_token', MyObtainToken.as_view()]
```

Comment: except few typos, suggested solution is a working one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@action` of an existing ModelViewSet for brevity:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["get"],
        url_path=r"current",
    )
    def current_user(self, request):
        return Response(
            UserSerializer(request.user, context={"request": request}).data
        )
```

And then `GET` it at:
http://localhost:8000/yourapi/users/current/