# How to get user in Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm using the Django REST framework and I'm trying to get the user like this in one of my class-based views:

```
class ListPDF(PDFTemplateView):
    """
    Return a PDF 
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    template_name = 'pdf.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

but for some reason I keep getting the error `User matching query does not exist`. I'm using the `rest_framework.authtoken` for authentication.

I've investigated and when I don't log in through the admin section the user is anonymous even though the user token is sent with the request. How do I get the user object in this view?

**Update

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212188/get-user-object-from-token-string-in-drf):

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
user = Token.objects.get(key='token string').user
```

but is there not an easier way to get the user?

Comment: we can access logged in user with `self.request.user`. No query required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added TokenAuthentication to `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`:

```
# settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    ...
}
```

Docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

---

Edit: I've noticed that you are subclassing `PDFTemplateView`. Did you write it yourself? Is it inherited from the DRF's `APIView`?